# Transposing a table with columns turning into row value

Tags: sql, vertica

I have the following table:

```
id      purch_d7   purch_d30     
 1         10             25
 2          5             15
```

and i want to transpose/pivot it into this format

```
 id     purchase_count   purch_window
  1           10         purch_d7
  1           25         purch_d30 
  2            5         purch_d7
  2           15         purch_d30
```

How would I go about doing this in Vertica? Also, if were to want to pivot/transpose the output back to the original view, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT id,purch_d7 as purchase_count,'purch_d7' as purch_window FROM T
UNION ALL 
SELECT id,purch_d30,'purch_d30' FROM T
```

Comment: it works for the first portion of my question which is the initial transpose, but then I don't have a way to repivot it back to the original table structure.

Answer (score 0):

I like to let the code show what I'm trying to do. I'm pivoting named columns vertically to value and 'value name'. So I add value names in an additional table that I supply.

Here goes:

```
WITH
-- don't add this first one to your query - it's just your data ...
input(id,purch_d07,purch_d30) AS (
          SELECT  1,10,25
UNION ALL SELECT  2, 5,15
)
,
-- real WITH clause starts here ...
-- add the possible purch types as an in-line table with labels
purch_window(purch_window) AS (
          SELECT 'purch_d07'
UNION ALL SELECT 'purch_d30'
)
SELECT 
  id
, CASE purch_window 
    WHEN 'purch_d07' THEN purch_d07
    WHEN 'purch_d30' THEN purch_d30
  ELSE NULL
  END AS purchase_count
, purch_window
FROM input CROSS JOIN purch_window
ORDER BY 1,3
;
```

Then pivoting back: ...

```
WITH
input(id,purch_d07,purch_d30) AS (
          SELECT  1,10,25
UNION ALL SELECT  2, 5,15
)
,
-- real WITH clause starts here ...
-- add the possible purch types as an in-line table with labels
purch_window(purch_window) AS (
          SELECT 'purch_d07'
UNION ALL SELECT 'purch_d30'
)
,
pivoted AS (
SELECT 
  id
, CASE purch_window 
    WHEN 'purch_d07' THEN purch_d07
    WHEN 'purch_d30' THEN purch_d30
  ELSE NULL
  END AS purchase_count
, purch_window
FROM input CROSS JOIN purch_window
)
SELECT
  id
, SUM(CASE purch_window WHEN 'purch_d07' THEN purchase_count END) AS purch_d07
, SUM(CASE purch_window WHEN 'purch_d30' THEN purchase_count END) AS purch_d30
FROM pivoted
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
;
```

All you have to do is to copy paste this into your vsql client (or whatever client you use to connect to Vertica ...)